# How to process XML files and update a table using SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two XML files `accepted.XML` and `rejected.XML` which have similar structure. One of the nodes of these files is **CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM**.

If the `CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM` is from accepted.xml, I need to update an SQL Server table with corresponding status as accepted. Same is the case with rejected.xml. My accepted.XML has the following structure:

#### Accepted.xml file layout:

```
 <CLAIM> 
      <CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM>1</CLIENT_CLAIM_NUM> 
      <Vendor_ASSIGNED_CLAIM_NUM>434772</Vendor_ASSIGNED_CLAIM_NUM> 
      <LASTNAME>#########</LASTNAME> 
      <Date>2012-01-06T00:00:00</Date>
 </CLAIM>
```

Also how can I send the count of claim numbers in each file by mail?

I used a Data flow task and an XML source to parse the XML. It gives the nodes as columns but how can I store it in a variable or update table with those columns. I cannot use a staging table as I wanted all this in a single package

Comment: @Siva : Thanks For the reply. I used a Data flow task and an XML source to parse the XML. It gives the nodes as columns but how can I store it in a variable or update table with those columns. I cannot use a staging table as I wanted all this in a single package

Answer (score 0):

To update a table, connect the output Data Flow Path to an OLE DB Command transformation. Construct a parameterized update statement e.g.

UPDATE MyTable SET Claim_Num = ?

Then map your column on the Column Mappings tab (within the 
OLE DB Command transformation).  You can add other parameters and map them to other columns as required.

To store the values in a Variable, first define a Variable with Data Type = Object.  Then connect the output Data Flow Path to a Recordset Destination, and specify that Variable.  Note this is actually a table of all the rows and columns.

To get a specific cell, next add a Foreach Loop Container to your Control Flow (downstream from your existing Data Flow task). Set the Enumerator to Foreach ADO Enumerator.  Specify your variable as the ADO object source variable.  Then on the Variable Mappings tab define new Variables for each column in the output.  Now any tasks within the Foreach Loop Container will get those Variables assigned with the values from each row on each iteration of the Loop.